# Supply Passphrase in the time of decryption in GPG

Tags: linux, gnupg, gpgme

While I'm using gpg manually it works fine. I got below screen("passphrase to unlock") I don't want to this screen mean I want to automate means I want to supply the password in time of decryption.

```
lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
x Please enter the passphrase to unlock the secret key for the OpenPGP certificate:  x
x "akhilesh (ak) <xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com>"                                               x
x 2048-bit RSA key, ID EC0BCE3F,                                                     x
x created 2015-03-02 (main key ID 3FA59C97).                                         x
x                                                                                    x
x                                                                                    x
x Passphrase _______________________________________________________________________ x
x                                                                                    x
x            <OK>                                                  <Cancel>          x
mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GPG automatic decryption password passing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482012/gpg-automatic-decryption-password-passing)

Comment: deleted space in code block to see whole message without the need to scroll

Comment: The answer should to be to use the gpg-agent - as the answer of proposed duplicate question suggests.

Comment: "I don't want to this screen mean I want to automate means I want to supply the password in time of decryption." What?

Answer (score 2):

To specify the passphrase at the time of decryption, use the flags `--passphrase <your passphrase>` and `--batch` (batch is needed for gpg2)

Example:

```
gpg2 --batch --passphrase mypassphrase -a -d my_encrypted_file
```