# I can’t get `git tag -s` to ask for my GPG password

Tags: git, gnupg

I can manually perform a gpg task that then prompts for my password via pinentry, with this password temporarily cached I can perform `git tag -s` and it works, other wise I get:

```
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled
error: gpg failed to sign the data
error: unable to sign the tag
```

I’m using Mac OS X 10.10.2 and have git and GnuPG 2.1 (modern) installed via homebrew. How can I get `git tag -s` to ask for my password?

Comment: Not a solution, but at least a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28484334/695343

Comment: This is often caused by an inability of gnupg to talk to gpg-agent, or of pinentry to talk to a display, due to missing/incorrect environment or configuration.  Compare the environment in which you perform the "manual task" with the environment in which you are invoking git.

Answer (score 2):

Try `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` - this should let you get prompted for a password (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/telling-git-about-your-signing-key).