# `git -S -m commit` failing to ask for password — Signing after moving from GPG mac to GPG shell

Tags: git, macos, github, gnupg, pgp

I am setting up new machine (macOS Sierra) for web development, and I have done `brew install gpg` which has installed `gpg2` and `gpg-agent`. I have copied my keys from `~.gnupg` on my old mac. I am *not* installing the mac interface GPG Suite which I had on the old machine as I really would prefer to use just command line.

I have set my git globals with the appropriate settings.

```
    git config --global user.name "Christopher Allen"
    git config --global user.email "ChristopherA@LifeWithAlacrity.com"
    git config --global user.mail "ChristopherA@LifeWithAlacrity.com"
    git config --global user.signingKey F8D36C91357405ED
```

When I try to commit change to a git repository where `git config commit.gpgsign=true` is required, on my old GPG Suite I get a popup window where it asks for my password. However, with GPG only, it does properly find my public key, but it does not prompt me for a password for signing.

```
    $ git commit -S -m "changed code"

    You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
    user: "Christopher Allen <ChristopherA@LifeWithAlacrity.com>"
    4096-bit RSA key, ID 357405ED, created 2015-04-16

    error: gpg failed to sign the data
    fatal: failed to write commit object
    $
```

Researching here, the only mention I see is at "[I can’t get `git tag -s` to ask for my GPG password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081834/i-can-t-get-git-tag-s-to-ask-for-my-gpg-password)" where it suggests the problem is with the environment variables for `gpg-agent` (with no suggested solution), or to use gpg-preset-passphrase function (which I'd prefer not to).

Checking further, it appears that `gpg-agent` isn't running:

```
    $ gpg-agent
    gpg-agent: no gpg-agent running in this session
```

I found this page https://blog.chendry.org/2015/03/13/starting-gpg-agent-in-osx.html that suggests to add this script to .bash_profile:

```
    [ -f ~/.gpg-agent-info ] && source ~/.gpg-agent-info
    if [ -S "${GPG_AGENT_INFO%%:*}" ]; then
        export GPG_AGENT_INFO
    else
      eval $( gpg-agent --daemon --write-env-file ~/.gpg-agent-info )
    fi
```

After sourcing this script, `gpg-agent` says:

```
    $ gpg-agent
    gpg-agent: gpg-agent running and available
```

However, I still have the same problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'd prefer not use the old GPG Suite, revert to GPG 1.0, or use gpg-preset-passphrase.

Thanks!

-- Christopher Allen

Answer (score 8):

What I actually did to solve this issue is:

#### Install pinentry

`brew install pinentry`

If that doesn't do the job then:

#### Tell GPG which tty to use when it asks for the password

`export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`

This actually fixed it for me.

You could also add this export to your `~/.bashrc` so that it will be exported automatically
*Don't forget to reload the file or launch a new session.*

An easy way to do it: `echo "export GPG_TTY=$(tty)" >> ~/.bashrc`

If you get this error:

#### `gpg-agent: no gpg-agent running in this session`

Add the script mentioned in the question to `~/.bashrc`  file as well.

```
[ -f ~/.gpg-agent-info ] && source ~/.gpg-agent-info
if [ -S "${GPG_AGENT_INFO%%:*}" ]; then
    export GPG_AGENT_INFO
else
    eval $( gpg-agent --daemon --write-env-file ~/.gpg-agent-info )
fi
```

#### Test to see if gpg is working

`echo "Hello" | gpg -s`

#### *Randomly it still doesn't ask for the passphrase*

When git won't ask me for the passphrase, sometimes I use the above test command to get prompted for it, which will get cached and then, I try to commit my changes.

#### Increase passphrase cache time

If you want to cache the passphrase for a longer period of time you can add the following line to the config file: `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
default-cache-ttl       86400
```

Comment: I see `WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect` in zsh - aren't you aware of any substitutions?

Comment: `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` alone worked form me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the problem is that I copied all the files from `~.gnupg`, which overwrote files created by `brew install gpg` (probably one of the `.conf` files.

I uninstalled gpg and all the associated sub-packages (there are a lot of them), copied only `pubring.gpg`, `secring.gpg` and `trustdb.gpg` into `~.gnupg` *FIRST*, then did `brew install gpg`. New `gpg.conf` and `gpg-agent.conf` were created.

-- Christopher Allen

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me.

I had to kill the agent and then called commit with `-S`:

`gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

`git commit -S -am "some message"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by starting a gpg-agent in daemon mode and then applying the GPG_AGENT_INFO environment variable it presented.

```
gpg-agent --daemon
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/Users/.../.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:58895:1; export GPG_AGENT_INFO;
```

In that same session, I did a `git tag -s` (note the lowercase 's') and I was properly prompted for my GPG passphrase.