# GPG: How to sign with multiple signatures with different passphrases?

Tags: encryption, batch-processing, gnupg, pgp

I have a job that runs periodically and signs/encrypts a file like so:

```
$ gpg --homedir /path/to/.gnupg -r key1@mydomain.com -r  key2@mydomain.com --local-user sig1@mydomain.com --batch --passphrase-file /path/to/gpg-password --sign -ea myfile
```

The command encrypts the file for two recipients: key1@mydomain.com and key2@mydomain.com. It signs the file with sig1@mydomain.com. It runs in batch mode as there is no human interactivity - this is an automated process. It gets the passphrase for the signature from /path/to/gpg-password.

What I would like to do is now sign the file with two signatures at the same time. Like so:

```
$ gpg --homedir /path/to/.gnupg -r key1@mydomain.com -r  key2@mydomain.com --local-user sig1@mydomain.com --local-user sig2@mydomain.com --batch --passphrase-file /path/to/gpg-password --sign -ea myfile

gpg: skipped "sig2@mydomain.com": bad passphrase
```

It works fine in interactive mode (eg. without --batch), I just have to supply the two passphrases via the command line. However, in batch mode it fails as it tries to get the signatures from the file. The signature is only valid for one of the signing keys.

From the man page:

> --passphrase-file `file`
>
> Read  the  passphrase  from file `file`. Only the first line will be read from file `file`. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied.

**How do I tell it what the password is for each key?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else in the same situation as me, I ended up working around this apparent deficiency of gpg by editing one of the signing keys to have the same password as the other (the password stored in the gpg-password file). This doesn't compromise security in this instance since the password is stored in a text file anyway - the real security is the password of the user that this commands runs from and the fact that the secret keys are kept secret). You can change the password on a key by doing `gpg --edit-key <key_id>`, then `passwd`. Don't forget to `save` after.

Answer (score 3):

You have different options.

- Completely remove the passwords, since they're stored somewhere anyway.
- Use the same password (as you already discovered).
- Use the `gpg-agent` and preset the passphrase. I'm unsure whether this is GnuPG 2-only (usually installed as `gpg2`, maybe to be installed from a `gnupg2` package). Presetting the passphrase is as easy as [running `gpg-preset-passphrase --preset [fingerprint]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482012/gpg-automatic-decryption-password-passing/28484334#28484334). You will have to run this command for each of the keys individually, and make sure to cache the passphrase for a given time (at least the processing time of adding all the passphrases, and then signing the file you want to sign).
- For the sake of completeness, but impractical: sign the file individually for each key, then take apart the OpenPGP packets and recombine them adding all the signatures one after the other. Signing with multiple keys just creates multiple signature packets.

Comment: Thanks! I had been looking into gpg-agent bit decided it wasn't worth the trouble right now. I getting rid of the passwords is a little dangerous just because these secret keys are stored elsewhere. But if they weren't then yeah, the passwords are meaningless.

Comment: Using `gpg-agent` isn't that complicated, and has the advantage that you could actually completely remove the passphrase from the application and heavily remove exposure of the private key to it. You will have to do so anyway to support ECC keys, which are only supported starting with GnuPG 2.1 (and GnuPG 2 removed the `--passphrase` options).

Comment: I was pointed out to the fact that `--passphrase` is actually still supported by GnuPG 2 and 2.1, if the `--batch` option is set.